# working framework locally

Tags: dojo

Iam trying to create a application that should work offline without internet connection. 
I gave as below to point to local dojo.js so that can work without internet connection.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/dojo-release-1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" dojo-data-config="parseOnLoad:true">
```

Do i need to do something else?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to narrow down the issue much.  Are you serving Dojo from a web server?  Are you sure your path is correct?  Is your document's HTML well-formed?

Comment: That attribute should be `data-dojo-config`. Are there any network request errors or any errors in the console when you try to load the local file? Is there a closing `<script>` tag for the local file?

Comment: Thanks for our time.yes, i'am closing the script tag and their are no errors which i can see. i have downloaded the dojo required files and kept under webcontent of my web application. Path is as follows: WebContent\dojo-release-1.9.3--contains dijit,dojox and dojo folders. Is that i need to load other than dojo.js ?

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser tools, is it retrieving the dojo.js script?

Answer (score 0):

Try including dojo like the following code if the WebContent folder is in the same directory as your main html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="WebContent/dojo-release-1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" dojoConfig="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: true" ></script>
```

The isDebug parameter set to true will display more info in the console when loading the page, especially useful for Firefox and the Firebug console.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. But still i could not able to work dojo without internet connection, i mean i downloaded dojo 1.9.3 API and kept under webcontent of web application folder.and trying to import required files to work still something is missing that i need to add. I have imported as below:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">